# how to set the minimum media segment in Playlist in iOs

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming, playlist, avplayeritem

I have sample media playlist and is it possible to set the minimum media segments in the playlist ?

Here is an example of a Media Playlist:

```
   #EXTM3U
   #EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10

   #EXTINF:9.009,
   http://media.example.com/first.ts
   #EXTINF:9.009,
   http://media.example.com/second.ts
   #EXTINF:3.003,
   http://media.example.com/third.ts
```

As shown in above, AVPlayerItem should be able to play only when minimum 3 media segments are present in playlist file.
Is there any document specifying this in HLS ??

Thanks